# Várias TextView

Tags: android, textview

Queria Saber se tem como eu adicionar uma TextView em um layout pelo java.
tipo tenho um xml que tem uma TextView e na class Activity uso o setContentView() para vincular os dois, mas eu queria colocar mais TextView no Layout pelo Java e não pelo xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso basta criar um objeto do tipo [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Ao criarmos esse objeto, precisamos passar o parâmetro `Context`

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

Agora é necessário definir o tamanho do elemento. Para isso iremos utilizar o método `setLayoutParams` e nele iremos passar um objeto do tipo `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams()`.

```
textView.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, //Largura
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  //Altura
) );
```

Pronto. Criamos nosso TextView através do Java. Agora só precisamos utilizar o método `addView` da View principal do seu XML.

**Código de Exemplo:**

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
) );
textView.setText("Olá mundo");

ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView( textView );
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.valdeirsantana.stackoverflow.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Para criar múltiplos TextView, basta envolver o código de exemplo dentro de um `for`

Comment: esta dando erro nesse codigo ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.container); e se eu colocar ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container); da erro na hora de add a View

Comment: @Francianderson Qual erro? você está colocando o ID correto (como no exemplo do XML) ?